# TCL Strip expression (Varying chars)

Tags: regex, string, tcl, strip

If i have a string such as:

foo_image_v001.ext

that could just as easily say

bar_image_v001.ext

How can i use TCL to strip the first underscore and everything to the right of it, leaving me with just 'foo' or 'bar'

Im normally a python guy, not very versed in TCL, but it will work best in this case if i can just get it to work =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace everything after the first `_`

```
set new [regsub {_.*} $old {}]
```

Comment: Cool this worked great! So i guess regsub is TCL's version of re from python? not sure what the -all does, and im guessing {_.*} is the expression saying after underscore, any character, for the full length? then $old is my filename, and {} is what im 'sub'ing those chars with (Blank in our case) correct?

Comment: [`regsub`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/regsub.htm) is for the substitution. Yes, you are correct. For matching, there is also [`regexp`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/regexp.htm). Regular Expressions are very common in most programming languages.

Comment: You don't need the `-all` there, as the RE will match to te end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it:

```
set filename foo_image_v001.ext
set prefix [regsub {_.*} $filename ""]
```

the regsub looks for the pattern `{_.*}` in $filename, and replace it with nothing `""`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use this?

```
set string "foo_image_v001.ext"

regexp -- {^([^_]+)} $string - var
```

`foo` gets stored in `$var`.

Comment: can you let me know why id use this method instead of 
[regsub -all {_.*} $old {}]

Im just not getting the double dash (regexp -- )
or {^([^_]+)}
at first glance i cant tell what the ^( is. does it mean keep all until... then [^_]+) is remove _and all trailing in $string ?

Comment: This matches all the sequence from the beginning (`^`) followed by non `_` characters. Unnecessary `()` to get the result. `--` means end of switches (important if your regexp starts with `-`). Saves `foo` to `-` as well. `regexp {^[^_]+} $old new` does the same job.

Comment: @user1917081 Instead of actually looking for everything after an underscore, and substituting by nothing, it just captures everything before an underscore (the first one) and assigns it to a variable `$var`. The brackets and end of switches (and catching in a variable that way) is just a matter of preference for consistency in my regexp's.

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to break out a regular expression for this:

using `string` commands:

```
set prefix [string range $filename 0 [expr {[string first _ $filename] - 1}]]
```

Also, if you split the string on underscores, what you want is the first element in the resulting list:

```
set prefix [lindex [split $filename _] 0]
```